# Retrieving icons out of dlls found in registry

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, icons

I'm currently trying to get a windows explorer like program up and running (via telerik). 
For that I'm using 2 steps to get the icons:

1. Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fileNameAndPath).ToBitmap();
2. If the 1. one fails I'm using the icon found as default icon for the extension in the registry.

So far so goot, I'm finding icons inside the searched files and I extract "C:\WINDOWS\system32\imageres.dll,-102" from the registry.

I now have seen a few solutions there that say that you have to use SHGetFileInfo or a third party tool,... . I'm not sure though HOW SHGetFileInfo is to be used in this context (tried a few times now to no avail).

So my question is what would I have to put into the parameters as my attempts here so far have
brought only exceptions when I tried to process the icon.

```
Telerik.WinControls.NativeMethods.SHFILEINFO shFileInfo = new NativeMethods.SHFILEINFO();
Telerik.WinControls.NativeMethods.SHGetFileInfo(fileNameAndPath, Telerik.WinControls.NativeMethods.SHGFI_SMALLICON, ref shFileInfo, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shFileInfo), Telerik.WinControls.NativeMethods.SHGFI_SMALLICON);
Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shFileInfo.hIcon).ToBitmap();
```

*Also as info when possible I want to use: Telerik.WinControls.NativeMethods.SHGetFileInfo (from what I've seen there seems to be no big difference to the nontelerik version of that method).

As a note: Even though I found out how to do it with ExtractIconEx (how to do that posted as answer) I would still prefer using SHFileInfo if possible as that would mean I would not neet to include an external dll)*

Answer (score 0):

A working variant would be using ExtractIconEx instead of SHFileInfo (even though I would prefer SHFileInfo).

If I have the value of the key from teh registry in the string variable keyValue
(thus "C:\WINDOWS\system32\imageres.dll,-102"):

```
string[] splitKeyValue = keyValue.ToString().Split(',');
IntPtr iconLarge = new IntPtr();
IntPtr iconSmall = new IntPtr();
ExtractIconEx(splitKeyValue[0], Convert.ToInt32(splitKeyValue[1]), ref iconLarge, ref iconSmall, 1);
Image returnImage = Icon.FromHandle(iconLarge).ToBitmap();
```

This would get me the large icon.

Also somewhere in the baseclass I would need to put in the following lines:

```
     [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern int ExtractIconEx(string stExeFileName, int nIconIndex, ref IntPtr phiconLarge, ref IntPtr phiconSmall, int nIcons);
```